# Getting weird characters when converting NSArray to JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am getting some weird characters when converting a NSArray containing NSDictionaries to a JSON string. 
I tried using both SBJson and NSJSONSerialization with the same result.

The NSDictionary is populated with the content of the address book, with the contact name, email and phone number, and are mostly in hebrew.

The characters look like this:

> \327\237

I could not find any information about this, help anyone?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT ***

Here is a snippet of the JSON:

```
[
    {"fname":"סתם טקסט"},
    {"fname":"סתם טקסט"},
    {"fname":"נ\327\231ר"}
]
```

its supposed to be:
    [
        {"fname":"סתם טקסט"},
        {"fname":"סתם טקסט"},
        {"fname":"ניר"}
    ]

And i am getting the JSON by using the following code:

```
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:ContactsArray options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[jsonData bytes]]);
```

Comment: Show some code. How are you getting from `NSArray` to `\327\237`?

Comment: You are probably seeing escaped output from NSString's `-description` method (used in debugger/print-object output)

Comment: What you should do: 1) Create a *small* JSON file that shows the problem and show it to us. - 2) Show your code, the result and the expected result.

Comment: Why do you think those characters are in any way weird?

Comment: The output of `NSLog(@"jsonData=%@", jsonData)` might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

These characters are octal escape codes. I prefer to look at things in hex. `\327` and `\237` are `0xD7` and `0x9F` in hex.

I looked up [`U+00D7`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d7/index.htm) and [`U+009F`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9f/index.htm) (unicode characters). They are MULTIPLICATION SIGN and APPLICATION PROGRAM COMMAND. That doesn't make sense in this context, so a straight conversion is not the way to go.

Next, I thought [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding. `D7 9F` [decodes](http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php) as [`U+05DF`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5df/index.htm). This is HEBREW LETTER FINAL NUN. That makes sense in this context.

So, I'm guess the data you are seeing in UTF-8 characters that are not understood and octal escaped. JSON doesn't support octal escapes, so I'm guessing it's `NSLog()` or whatever you are using to print the JSON that is doing the escaping.

Comment: Actually it makes a lot of sense, but could it be that the problem is caused by converting the NSData to NSString and not by the NSLog?

Comment: @shay I don't know, but I don't think so. You can log `jsonData` directly. This should get you a hex dump: `NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [jsonData debugDescription]);`. Also, I would try `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` instead of `-stringWithUTF8String`.